# Matlab How to perform substraction for multiple cell arrays?

Tags: matlab, loops, cell-array, subtraction

The code below is only for 2 cell arrays, named `B` and `C`

```
A=cellfun(@minus, B, C, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

I want to perform a loop to be able to perform substraction for all my cell arrays. 
Example of B{i} and C{i} are below:

```
B{1}=[0.435] 
B{2}=[0.333] [0.532] 
B{3}=[0.021] [0.432] [0.312]        //command window output

C{1}=[0.211] 
C{2}=[0.243] [0.116] 
C{3}=[0.553] [0.212] [0.375]        //command window output

B{1}-C{1}
B{2}-C{2}
B{3}-C{3}
```

I tried to include `{i}` behind `A` , `B` and `C` to become something like:

```
A{i}=cellfun(@minus, B{i}, C{i}, 'UniformOutput' , false)
```

However, it seems like it's not working. Is there any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I was actually in the process of writing an answer to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828453/matlab-how-to-perform-substraction-for-cell-arrays-inside-looping) when you deleted it... Please avoid reposting questions!

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. is cellfun for multiple cell arrays? because it only can minus between two.

Comment: your code posted is not even valid syntax, you can't write `C{3}=[0.553] [0.212] [0.375]`! Next time include code we can actually copy/paste, and it would work

Comment: Those are actually my command window output.

Comment: I knew that, but it just makes it harder for us to help you.. You could see there was a confusion in your previous question exactly because of this, others just couldn't figure out the format your data was in. The more clear your question is, the better your chances are of getting helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT:

You have unnecessary **nested** cell-arrays, i.e `B` is a cell-array of cell-arrays, and `B{i}` is a cell-array of numbers.

If you want to keep that format, here is one way to compute the result using `cellfun` (`A` will also be a cell-array of cell-arrays of numbers):

```
% exiting data
B = cell(3,1);
B{1} = {0.435};
B{2} = {0.333, 0.532};
B{3} = {0.021, 0.432, 0.312};
C = cell(3,1);
C{1} = {0.211};
C{2} = {0.243, 0.116};
C{3} = {0.553, 0.212, 0.375};

A = cellfun(@(b,c)cellfun(@minus, b, c, 'Uniform',false), B, C, 'Uniform',false);
```

---

Otherwise I suggest you cut down on the level of nesting, and use this instead:

```
% note the difference between square-brackets and curly-brackets
B = cell(3,1);
B{1} = [0.435];
B{2} = [0.333, 0.532];
B{3} = [0.021, 0.432, 0.312];
C = cell(3,1);
C{1} = [0.211];
C{2} = [0.243, 0.116];
C{3} = [0.553, 0.212, 0.375];
```

Now you can compute the result using a single `cellfun` (no nesting):

```
A = cellfun(@minus, B, C, 'Uniform',false)
```

Comment: My B{i} and C{i} consist of different size array but every time when B{i} minus C{i} they are of the same size. I need to loop them. Above is a simple example of size 3 cell.